# Team Foundation Data Migration from TFS2010/SQL Server 2008R2 to TFS2012/SQL Server 2012 server

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010, tfs-2012

TFS2010/SQL Server 2008 R2 standalone hardware has crashed. I have the windows backups for the machine.

Can I migrate these databases directly to a new TFS2012/SQL Server 2012 setup?

This would save time but I would like some opinions from anyone that has attempted this forced upgrade. I have read a number of blogs from other efforts but have not found this specific route. My main concern is the validity of the "Tfs..." databases when I try to attach them to the new SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

However I would recommend that you install the latest version of TFS which is TFS 2017 Update 1. There is no value in maintaining old software infrastructure when it is free to upgrade. Since you are on TFS 2010 you should go to TFS 2013.5 first... Then to 2017.

[image]

Comment: That is a definitive answer. My thanks for the roadmap. However - any ideas on what i will encounter : "My main concern is the validity of the "Tfs..." databases when I try to attach them to the new SQL"

Comment: I read horror stories about tfs db's recovered from win backup that have remapping problems. BTW - we have the new server set up and running. I am about to drop teh existing dbs and replace them with the recoverd ones.